# Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 - No Intellisense?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Visual Studio 2013 Experts:

How do you enable intellisense when editing a single source file (or can you)?

1. Start Visual Studio 2013 Professional (Version 12.0.30626.00 Update 3 RC) -- fully registered.
2. Click on "File -> Open -> File ..." and select a VB.Net source file, ie: filename.vb
3. Type a statement such as:
   if ( String.
              ^--- at that point isn't intellisense supposed to list
                   all members of the ASP.NET String class?????

Nothing happens; what setting am I missing?

OR

Does intellisense only work in Projects and not with individual source files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellisense only works when working within a project.  The project type determines the internal compilers used to create intellisense - without this, you just have a plain text editor.

Comment: Figures!! Duh! - I just thought (hoped?) that by 2013 the VS "editor" would have enough smarts to know what language was being edited (perhaps future versions will allow this or perhaps an option in the EDIT menu will allow us to select a language - Microsoft suggestion; wink wink).  -- Thanks!

Comment: @user1377587 Yeah - for the main languages, it requires a project.  It's a pain when using F# :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the file type. In your case, for a `VB` source file there will be no intellisense without a project.

On the other hand, for files such as `Html`, `js` it is available even without a project.